# Get upercase within String Value

Tags: vba, string, text, symbols, uppercase

I am currently working on a tool to automatically send out emails.
Within this tool one variable is the pathway in which the attachment is to be found. 
The file names are automatically generated within a folder, but sometimes got strange symbols and/or uppercase letters, like this: "Sⁿkwrld.xlsx".
By collecting this value within a string, VBA retrieves: "Snkwrld.xlsx". This results in not being able to find the right file.

Is there a way to fix this problem and let VBA retrieve the correct value with the uppercase "N"?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Remco Coppens

Comment: Can be please post snippet of the code , you are using

Comment: FWIW in what you show the `n` is *not* "uppercase". Uppercase `n` is `N`. From what I can tell, this looks like a "superscript", although I wouldn't think Windows would respect superscript formatting, thus not affecting the file name. Is it possible this is a special Unicode value? You need to figure out *exactly* what this is / where it's coming from in order to be able to detect it.

Comment: I don't know if it is a special unicode value, I looked it up but wasn't able to find it. The code I'm using is to detect if the file is present in the location described in the pathway. But I defined the problem in retrieving the file name. This because a msgbox shows "Snkwrld.xlsx" instead of "Sⁿkwrld.xlsx". This filename is the only file name which gives an error, and is the only one with superscript. If not possible to fix I will change the bron code which names the files to get the superscript out of it.